# Input color control chars in Textmate

Tags: textmate

I can use VIM to input these color control chars by "Ctrl-V, Esc" then it will show me ^[ as a special leading char for color control chars sequence.

How could I do this in Textmate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can select those from the character viewer (Menu Edit -> Special Characters, then search for 'escape'), but I think you'd be better off using an escaped form of that character, e.g. `\033` in Bash or `\x1b` in PHP. That, of course, would depend on what kind of document you're editing.

Comment: The unprintable char I can see in hex is 1B, which will show in textmate as a small grey Diamond.  

    `?[31m this is input by C-v Esc [31m ?[m`  
? indicate the unprintable char which is 1B in HEX  
the above line will show in red line in terminal

Comment: Are you editing the PS1 variable? Then you're using ANSI escape sequences, and you can use \033 instead of your "C-v Esc" character: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html